# save the action performed by context menu in vb.net forms app on pc reboot

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I have made a vb.net app which hides the utorrent and other less usable icons from tray. I used to fetch these icons in a listview in vb.net and on right clicking the program name, there appears a context menu which hides the icon. But after rebooting the system the icon appears again. Is there any way to save the event in mysettings.settings so that rebooting doesn't affect the  action taken... here's my code

```
Public Shared Sub hideTaskbarIcons(hide As Boolean, indexcnt As Integer) 
            buttonsOverflow = GetButtons(hwndOverflow)    
            SendMessage(FindTrayToolbarWindowOverflow, TB_HIDEBUTTON, indexcnt, hide)
end sub
```

Comment: This functionality is already built into Windows as the "Notification Area Icons" control panel applet.

Comment: yeah dats right... but if i want to make the change permanent.. then what to do.. i have tried My.Settings.Save() and My.Settings.Reload() but that didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The `My.Settings` object is for settings that are defined at build-time (such as the state of the application's own notification icon, for instance). Since you want to store the state of a variable number of application icons, you're better off with manually reading and writing an XML document with the [`System.Xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace. You could also store the states in the registry with the [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Either of those options will free you from the constraints of the application settings system.

Comment: thnx..it seems useful...i'll come back later